# Eclipse plugin for searching Expressions in Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I'm using very often **Expressions** tab in debug mode during programming. 
I usually put here source code variables to watch and check their status. If variable is just a primitive (String, Long, etc) it's easy to check value. Problem is that I want to check if more complex variable (like map of maps, or other nested collection) contains specific value that I'm looking for. 
Please look at the attached screenshot.

[image]

To check if cclasses variable contains value: "testName" I need to expand:

- cclasses
- first
- next
- item
- displayName

I would like to do it somehow automatically and search for phrase "testName" whole variable "cclasses".

Do you know if I can use any eclipse plugin to search whole variable by nested value inside of this variable?

Comment: You could use [Eclipse Conditional Breakpoints](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F)